# Sybase hash for validation + convert(varchar, ...)?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sap-ase

I've some tables that shouln't be modified after some final steps in a process.

To validate that it wasn't made any modifications (after the final state) I'm thinking about making an hash of all the columns. So, for each row I:

1. Make a varchar will all the columns (other data types are converted);
2. Save the hash result

In the future, to validate, I simply do the hash again and compare with the result obtained previously.

---

Is there a better way to do it?

If not, when converting the other data types to varchar, should I use `convert(varchar, ...)` or depending on the type of the data should I define a length to the `varchar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally if I were taking that approach I'd use a timestamp field instead of a hash.  That will automatically update any time anything happens to the row and is a whole easier than what your describing.

The verification approach would be similar to what you describe in your question.  To make auditing easy you could use a trigger to store the timestamp value off to another table.

Or... speaking of triggers.  If your true intent is to block updates entirely you could use a trigger to cancel the update entirely (unless it meets specific requirements that you set).

This is all assuming you have a reason for not just locking down the rights on the table by revoking update / delete rights to all users.  (which would be the easiest of all).

Comment: humm, how does the validation work? do I need to put the timestamp field in another table and afterwards compare both? Or is there another way?

Comment: I guess I figured you'd use the same approach you planned on using for your hash value, but sure if you wanted you could write a trigger to save the timestamp value off to a "audit" table and then check against that.

Comment: For that matter, if you were really serious about keeping rows from being changed you could write a trigger that would cancel anything that tried to change the row.

Comment: update your answer, put the audit table in the timestamp part and talk about the trigger option. I'll accept it afterwards (say something here)